# fixed layout when keyboard pops up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-softkeyboard

I have a listview contains of edittext and other components
when i click on edittext, the keyboard pops up which causes the list view go into bottom  of it
and clear any text in the edittext

any idea to fixed layout or to solve this problem

Item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:paddingTop="7dip"
        android:text="Mate name"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:drawablePadding="0dip"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eventname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/n" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:paddingTop="7dip"
        android:text="Match friend"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonpartner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:drawablePadding="0dip"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_friend" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editpartner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonpartner" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
        android:paddingTop="7dip"
        android:text="Start Mate date"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/d"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:drawablePadding="0dip"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_cal" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editd"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/d" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

addevent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/MyList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
         >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set your application to fullscreen mode. When you do so, the elements are fixed even when the keyboard pops up.

An example theme.xml file of mine:

```
<style name="theme_loading" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/loading</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textOptionsColor</item>
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/rbStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```